# Add field to content type through already installed module - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I have custom module and the module is already installed in production. Now I want to add one field(entity reference taxonomy field) to one of content type though this module. Since module is already installed in production I cant add the field configuration in config/install of module.

Can you please mention how can I add new filed without affecting current workflow ?

Comment: May be https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145848/add-field-to-existing-content-entity help you

Comment: That's a very annoying missing features on Drupal 8. I'm trying drush entity-updates Not sure it works.